# Less strict phone regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate a phone number with regular expressions in JavaScript.

I found lot of expression that match a specific pattern, such as `xxx-xxx-xxx`, but I'm looking for a less strict expression, that matches only numbers, and optionally `-`, `,` and `+` without restricting the number to a specific schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so how about just:

```
/^[0-9\-,+]+$/
```

or, if you want to allow spaces too:

```
/^[0-9\-,+\s]+$/
```

You might also want to require that phone numbers have at least *n* digits, which you could do like this:

```
/^[\-,+\s]*([0-9][\-,+\s]*){n,}$/
```

where you need to replace the `n` with the minimum number of digits you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([0-9]{3}[-,+]?){2}[0-9]{4}
```

[Here it is in action](http://regexr.com?33abm)